# Como selecciono un atributo especifico de un select en css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un formulario en donde tengo un select en donde muestra las prioridades, por ejemplo (Urgente, alta, etc.) y quisiera seleccionar desde css el select y un atributo para así darle un color, esto es lo que intente hasta ahora pero no me funciona

```
divShow.innerHTML += `
    <div>
        <p>${title} - <span class="priority">${prioritySelect}</span></p>
        <p>${description}</p> 
        <p>${datetimeInput}</p>
        <a class="dele-boton" onClick="deleteTasks('${title}')">Delete</a> 
    </div>`
```

Y quiero obtener en css el atributo "Urgente" para darle un color

```
.priority option[value="Urgente"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Como lo podría hacer, gracias de antemano por su ayuda...

Comment: Ese es el javascript y ahi estoy mostrando los valores que el usuario eligió y en el html hay una sección que es para elegir las prioridades de las tareas y esos ya tiene un color, pero cuando muestro las tareas ya creadas, alado del titulo quiero que muestre la prioridad que eligió el usuario, que ya lo hace pero quiero ponerle color también, espero que mi explicación sea bastante entendible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con los `data-attributes`, en el CSS:

```
[data-priority="Urgente"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Para ello solo tendrías que actualizar el HTML del siguiente modo:

```
<span class="priority" data-priority="${prioritySelect}">
   ${prioritySelect}
</span>
```

Comment: Si me funciono muchas gracias por la ayuda...